# Как сохранить данные в volume docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

У меня есть локальная база данных на компьютере и я хочу, чтобы ее значения появлялись и в контейнере.
Вот код docker compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: db
    env_file:
      - .env-prod
    volumes:
      - /postgres:/data_db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    env_file:
      - .env-prod
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - 5500:5500
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Что конкретно делает volumes ? Копирует папку /postgres в /data_db?
И как мне копировать данные с локальной базы данных в контейнер?